# Vuestore | htaccess | page goes to 404 before loading

Tags: apache, vue.js, .htaccess, vue-storefront

I have two domains.

farrwest.com (running vuestore on port 3000 and vuestore-api on 8080)

and

dev.farrwest.com (running vuestore on port 3001)

I have added `.htaccess` with rewrite rules on both domains root directory.

With the following configuration.

**farrwest.com:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule  ^api(.*)$  http://localhost:8080/api$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule  ^img/(.*)$  http://localhost:8080/img/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

**dev.farrwest.com:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dev.farrwest.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:3001/$1 [P,L]
```

Both of the sites load fine, except, before loading they goes to 404 page not found, then the page is loaded.

I would have gone for reverseproxy on apache virtualhost, but i could not find the configuration for it in cpanel.

And with htaccess i tried to find a way around, but have not found any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution:

Updated my .htaccess files as following.

**farrwest.com:**

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule  ^api(.*)$  http://localhost:8080/api$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule  ^img/(.*)$  http://localhost:8080/img/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

**dev.farrwest.com:**

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dev.farrwest.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://localhost:3001/$1 [P,L]
```